# Uploading PDF to Azure Blob Storage via Groovy - Issues with pictures

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I have the request to Upload a PDF from SFTP to Azure Blob which is working for text based PDF only.

If I have a PDF with pictures the PDF ulploaded is faulty (missing pictures)

If I use the "normal" bytearrayoutputsream and return a string I convert it back to PDF and it works.

The issue only occours using Azure methods:

I use this line of code to so:

```
def body = message.getBody(String.class) 
BlobOutputStream blobOutputStream = blob.openOutputStream()
blobOutputStream.write(body.getBytes())
blobOutputStream.close()
```

A correct PDF with pictures is expected. How to do so ?

Comment: Hello @Julian, Does this provided solution works for you : https://answers.sap.com/questions/13609184/upload-pdf-png-file-azureblob-from-cpi-damaged-pdf.html

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by **[Priyanka Chakraborti](https://people.sap.com/priyanka2018)** If using open connectors with Cloud Plateform intergation(CPI) is an option, then you can refer to the [***blogpost***](https://blogs.sap.com/2022/01/21/cloud-integration-with-commerce-azure-blob-storage-using-open-connectors/). The files will not be corrupted in that case.